# How to go to else condition if the element is not displaying Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, if-statement, webdriver

I am writing a piece of code in which in the if condition I am giving a condition that if the element is displayed they only go to **if** part otherwise if the element is not displayed then it should go to **else** part. But whenever it is coming to the if condition, it searches for the element and when it doesn't find it, it gives a timeout exception. What can be done ?

```
if(webDriver.findElementByXPath(btn).isDisplayed()){
//conditions
}
else{
//conditions
}
```

Comment: `.findElementByXPath()` is not in the Selenium API. The problem likely exists there. You should post the contents of that function.

Comment: @JeffC Thanks for the comment. I am actually working on a F/w which ultimately does the same thing as `driver.findElement(By.xpath())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can catch TimeoutException and other exceptions and execute same method for not display conditions and catch exception clause as:

```
try {
  if(webDriver.findElementByXPath(btn).isDisplayed()){
     //conditions
  }
  else{
     conditionsForNotDisplay();
  }
} catch (Exception e) {
  //log exception
  conditionsForNotDisplay();

}
```

Comment: I tired that but I am getting an error as: Timed out after 60 seconds waiting for presence of element located by: By.xpath

Comment: Maybe your exception is in previous line(s) , can you put the `try {` at the start of your code and try

Comment: previous element is not throwing exception, but still wrapped it around a try catch block but it also didn't help.

Comment: You were right, one of the statements was actually making the trouble. Marked your response as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You must not see the **TimeoutException** stemming out of the code block you have showcased. You need to modify your code block a bit to catch the **NoSuchElementException** exception as follows :

```
    try
    {
        WebElement my_element = webDriver.findElementByXPath(btn);
        if(element.isDisplayed()){
            //conditions
        }else{
            //conditions
        }
    }
    catch (NoSuchElementException e)
    {
        //conditions
    }
```

Comment: it is givng element not found exception.

Comment: Updated my answer to catch both `TimeoutException` and `NoSuchElementException`

Comment: again getting Timeout Exception.

Comment: No you shouldn't get a `TimeoutException` from the block of code you have put within the Question. I have removed the clause of `TimeoutException` from my code. If it is happening that is from some where else.

Comment: The problem was that I was assigning the findelement value in a variable, since there was no element, no value was getting assigned to the variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your else condition code either in handlers of TimeoutException and NoSuchElementException separately in different catch clause if you have to do something specific in each case or catch them in a single catch and add else code in handling them accordingly.

But below approach has a problem that if there is an exception thrown from else condition then else condition code will be executed twice.

```
try {
    WebElement element = webDriver.findElementByXPath(btn);
    if(element != null && element.isDisplayed()){
        //do something 
    } else {
        //handle else
    }
} catch (TimeoutException e) {
    //handle else
} catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
    //handle else
}
```

—-

```
try {
    WebElement element = webDriver.findElementByXPath(btn);
    if(element != null && element.isDisplayed()){
        //do something
    } else {
        //handle else
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    //handle else
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to check element is present in the views. create a boolean function with a boolean element as set to false.
Pass the web element to the boolean function if the element is displayed change status of the boolean element to true else false will be returned
** You can user Assert instead of sysout.

```
@Test
public void testLogin(){ 

  if(isElementPresent(errorLogin))
         {            
             System.out.println("Please enter valid email id and password");
         }
         else
         {
             System.out.println("Login successfull..........Enjoy");

         }
}
public boolean isElementPresent(WebElement ele)
     {
        boolean ElementPresent=false;
        try {
            if(ele.isDisplayed())
            {
                ElementPresent=true;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Element is not proeset " +e);
        }
        return ElementPresent;
     }
```